# Is it possible to have two divs inside a div, one docked left and one right, such that one shrinks when space is unavailable?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a web application with a panel. Inside this panel I want to have a constant-size button on the left, and some status text on the right. When the window shrinks, I want the text that is docked on the right to shrink to accommodate everything.

**Example:**

Initial:

`[[BUTTON]           [Status text]]`

When shrunk:

`[[BUTTON][Sta...]]`

Two ways I know to get this docking are:

- to make the `Status text` div `position: absolute`, but this takes it out of the flow and would just make it overlap
- to use floats, but this causes the `float:right` element to just wrap to the next line when space runs out

I'm looking for a solution that leverages the browser positioning engine as much as possible as opposed to manually calculating things.

Is there a way to do it? Only concerned with modern browsers.

Comment: there are newer css overflows that can help, like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Comment: Question has been asked hundreds of times, but the way you asked the question does add a good entry for people using Google.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need support only modern browsers you can use flexboxes for this. Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/igoradamenko/dkpvo11e/).

HTML:

```
<div>
  <button>Button</button>
  <span>Some text here...</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

span {
  overflow: hidden;
  -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I think this is what you are asking for https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/komfhjdj/7/

You can do this many different ways however the two key attributes in my example are   `white-space: nowrap;` and `overflow: hidden;`

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <input class="button" type="button" value="button">
  <div class="right">
    Some text tttttt
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.button {
  width: 100px;
  float: left
}

.right {
  width: calc(100% - 100px);
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
  background-color: lightblue;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Although I appreciate all the up votes, please look at Igor Adamenko's answer below, I think it is a better answer then mine.

Comment: I can see the calc() rule being useful alongside the other answer too. Both are helpful things to know.

Answer (score -1):

You could turn the outer container into a flexbox and work from there

```
<div style="display:flex; justify-content:space-between" class="container">
  <button>
  <p>Status Text</p>
</div>
```

The `justify-content` means that all the elements within the container will be pushed as far as apart as can fit within the box

Comment: This is essentially the same answer as @Igor Adamenko provides, but the `display` rule here is incorrect.

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake. I've updated the post to fix that